# Selecting 2 random rows from SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random

What would be the fastest way to select 2 random rows from an SQL table ? (SQL only or not)
I am using MySQL on PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: See this answer by Skliwz.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191342/random-record-from-a-database-table-t-sql

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 2
```

What you will get is two rows in database default order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 2`

Comment: Woudln't this become noticeably slower the more tuples the table contains?