# SQL - Insert a random; already made record into a new table. Using stored procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am creating a make booking stored procedure.

In a `Tutor` table I have already added tutor records.

The `TutorId` is referenced in the `Booking` table by a foreign key constraint.

After manual input from visual studio for generic booking questions, I would like a random `TutorId` to be assigned with this `BookingId`.

Comment: I removed the incompatible atabase tags.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MYSQL.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please add the SQL code (DDL) for the tables and the procedure you have at the moment. Also show some sample data for before and after your procedure runs (expected output).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 TutorId FROM Tutor ORDER BY NEWID()
```

This will return you a random record from your Tutor table.

A `NEWID()` is generated for each row and the table is then sorted by it. The first record is returned (i.e. the record with the "lowest" GUID).

Source: [Random record from a database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191342/random-record-from-a-database-table-t-sql#191348)